# Is it bad practice to change the name of a menu item after the function has been used?

Tags: user-expectation, menu, terminology, names

We have a function on our website where the user is able to link a page to other existing pages. When a page has links to other pages, a special icon is displayed on the page, through which the user can view the links and move to those pages.

There is a function under a menu that lets the user "manage links". Under that function, they can remove existing links or add new ones. The problem is, that if there are no links on the page yet, "manage links" is not really the most natural option to present; as there are none yet.

Would it be bad to have the option labeled "add new link" (or something similar) if no links are added yet, and after that the option would change to "manage links"? Or do you feel like "manage links" is a natural way for the user to add the first link on the page?

[image: this would be the case if the menu item name changed after adding a link]

and no, unfortunately we are not allowed to have two separate menu items, so that there would be always the option to both add new links and to manage existing ones.

I couldn't really find any concrete information on this subject, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you post a screen grab? Or a section of it showing the menu?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to show it (and it also is not in english), but the function is under a meatball menu that is displayed on the page. It has other options as well. So basically, the menu would have the option "Add new link". If the user adds a link, the next time they navigate to the meatball menu, the option would be "Manage links" instead of "add new link". I'm mainly wondering if it is more confusing to have a menu item with a changing name, or to just have the option to "manage links", even if there are no links yet. The user will know if any links exist on the page already.

Comment: Try mocking it instead, something to work with is better than nothing

Comment: I added a mock to the original post

Comment: Can the add a link to one page or several? Do the links to the page ever change status, expire or become unavailable? How many links is the user allowed to add?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you are on the right track.

Having **two options** depending on the state of the page seems the optimal way forward. It makes total sense to have the option **"Add Link"** if the user has not added any links yet, so they know what exactly they need to be doing when they click on that option; and the option **"Edit Link"**, once the user has added a link, for the same reason.

Based on my experience, copywriting needs to adapt to the specific context and in your case having two wordings will most likely make things clearer to your users.

Good luck!